# Obtain below date format in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Please suggest how to format date into this format `'05/23/2014 09:56:07 AM'` in SQL server. 
Is there a style code to be passed to `CONVERT function`   ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731214/date-format-in-sql-server?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sql Server 2012 onwards you can use following query:-

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'G');
```

Otherwise convert function is used to coverts the date into desired fpormat.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select convert(varchar(50), getdate(), 131)
```

for detail please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: That is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM` I was looking for `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM`

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
declare @d datetime = getdate()

select 
    @d, 
    CONVERT ( varchar(30), @d, 101 ) ,
    convert( varchar(12),  @d, 101) +  stuff( right( convert( varchar(26),@d, 109 ), 15 ), 7, 7, ' ' ) as formatedDate
```